# Changing contrast in XFCE

Tags: display, xfce

I am using XFCE on a matte screen notebook and quite unhappy with the black balance of it.

Is it possible to change contrast in XFCE? I am not looking to change `gamma` using

```
xgamma -gamma x.x
```

If not, is there any way on different Desktop Environments?